# Distribution queue with Python

Tags: python, random

Maybe someone can help me or give me a light. I have a list of people's names. Example: "Saulo", "Maria", "Fernando"

I need to create automatic distribution among these people without repeating a person before the list is complete.

Using Python shuffle, it is not certain that the result is always random.

```
import random

mylist = ["Saulo", "Maria", "Fernando"]
random.shuffle(mylist)
```

Example: If Saulo receives an item, he will only receive it again when Maria and Fernando receive it too.

Ideas?

Comment: Your question is unclear. `random.shuffle()` is always random, but I'm not sure what this question has with randomness. Can't you just assign each item to the next person in a circular fashion?

Comment: For a brute force solution, for short lists you can generate all permutations of your list and select permutations where indices of `Maria` and `Fernando` are smaller than the index of `Saulo`. Take a look at `itertools.permutations`. This will not work for longer lists, however, as permutations will grow very quickly with the size of the list. You can also think about taking `Maria` and `Fernando` out of the list and permuting the rest of the sublist, constructing new lists that way. But, yes, your question is a little unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think shuffling is really part of the problem. You can make a circular index

```
mylist = ["Saulo", "Maria", "Fernando"]
i = 0
l = len(mylist) 
while i < 10:
    print(f'Give item to {mylist[i % l]}")
    i += 1
```

If you want to prevent duplicates, use a set rather than a list

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can achieve this using numpy, as you can use one array to order another:

```py
import numpy as np
mylist = np.array(["Saulo", "Maria", "Fernando"])
ordering = np.arange(0, len(mylist))

np.random.shuffle(ordering)  # shuffle your order

ii = 0
while True:
    giveto = mylist[ordering][ii]  # apply the ordering and select current element
    
    # implement what you want to do with the name

    ii += 1
    if ii == len(mylist):
        np.random.shuffle(ordering)
        ii = 0
```

If you scale mylist to a large number of names, you might want to move `mylist[ordering]` out of the while loop for performance reasons and only order when a new shuffle is performed